# If argument in maven Surefire plugin, skip E2E tests

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

I couldn't seem to find anything on this but I'm curious if I can pass an argument during runtime to skip all of our projects E2E tests.

Is there anyway for me to do something like the segregated exclude block in the following pom example?

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
      <excludes>

         <exclude unless="${skip.E2E.tests}> **/*E2E*.java</exclude>

         <exclude>**/IT*.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then I could just call `mvn clean install -Dskip.E2E.tests=true`. Anybody seen anything like this?

I suppose I could do something like...

```
<exclude>${name.of.tests.to.exclude}</exclude>
```

and then `mvn clean install -Dname.of.tests.to.exclude=**/*E2E*.java`but I would prefer to get an easy true or false argument to set rather than this in case some of the tests I want to skip do not include E2E and I need to add them to a list.

Comment: I believe the `mvn load install` was probably a typo, there is no `load` phase in Maven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell just from the snippet of your pom that you are showing, but it looks like you are using surefire for both your unit and your e2e tests.  Instead, you should consider using the [failsafe](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) plugin for e2e.

One benefit is that the e2e tests will run in a different stage so you get the behavior looking for by default. They are run during the verify stage of the project build. So, you can run `mvn test` to run unit tests only.

You can configure your project to use fail-safe like this:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Run them using: `mvn verify`

Running `mvn install -DskipITs` will skip only integration tests, while still running unit tests.

And running `mvn install -DskipTests` will skip both integration and unit tests.

Comment: Thank you for that. I was experiencing some issues with Jacoco & Powermock when trying to set up a sonarQube server. One of the issues I resolved by disabling the Failsafe plugin.  I had forgotten to go back and try to divide our E2E tests and UT into their respective plugins. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement such a condition, you could use [Maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) and have two configuration:

- The default one as part of the normal build, not skipping the E2E tests
- the profiled one skipping them

The profile could be then activated upon property or direct activation.

As an example you could have:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/IT*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>skip.E2E.tests</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>skip.E2E.tests</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*E2E*.java</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/IT*.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Note: the default Maven Surefire Plugin applying to normal build and then a profiled one.

Running:

```
mvn clean install
```

Will not activate the profile and your build will skip the tests. While running:

```
mvn clean install -Pskip.E2E.tests
```

or

```
mvn clean install -Dskip.E2E.tests=true
```

Will activate the profile and as such add the exclusion to the tests execution.

So this is exactly the scenario you were looking for, I presume.

---

Alternatively and as suggested by @AndrewEisenberg in the another answer, you could use the [Maven Failsafe Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) for different type of tests. The main two differences are that: it has different phase bindings AND when it fails, it does it in a safer way. As from official documentation:

> If you use the Surefire Plugin for running tests, then when you have a test failure, the build will stop at the integration-test phase and your integration test environment will not have been torn down correctly.
>
> The Failsafe Plugin is used during the integration-test and verify phases of the build lifecycle to execute the integration tests of an application. The Failsafe Plugin will not fail the build during the integration-test phase, thus enabling the post-integration-test phase to execute

Comment: One other important things is that maven-failsafe-plugin has a different naming schema for test....

Comment: Thank you for this post, this definitely fits what I was asking for. If I have issues in the future where I can not use a conditional statement(like one can inside pom ant tasks) this will be of much assistance to me. Though after reading @AndrewEisenbergs answer, I believe that would be a more conventional way to solve this problem, no need to reinvent the wheel ;)